# Como remover um diretório no Windows mesmo que esteja em uso?

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal

Tenho um serviço de banco de dados rodando em um diretório conhecido `C:\meuBanco\exe\` e agora desenvolvi um atualizador deste serviço, que executa os seguintes passos:

1. Para o serviço
2. Exclui a pasta `exe`: `rd /s /q %DIRSERV%\exe\`
3. Descompacta o zip com o novo serviço na pasta `exe`

O problema está no passo 2, onde eventualmente não é possível excluir a pasta, pois está em uso.
Mas quando a atualização é executada, ela pode excluir a pasta, pois não deveria ter qualquer processo bloquando a pasta `exe`.

Por isso pergunto: **existe uma forma de forçar a remoção de um diretório no Windows mesmo que esteja em uso?**

Comment: Acredito que precise elevar privilegios ao nivel do de sistema, afinal, esse recurso é por segurança,  pra ninguem apagar algo que esteja em uso e comprometer  outra aplicação que esteja fazendo este uso.

Comment: @diegofm Já rodo a atualização como administrador. Há outro nível possível?

Comment: Sim, há outros niveis de sistema acima do administrador, tanto é que existem pastas e arquivos que você, mesmo como admin, não consegue acessar no windows

Comment: Tente isso: http://stackoverflow.com/a/98069/5524514

Comment: Finalizar os executáveis ou arquivos que estão abertos no diretório não resolve? para finalizar com o `takkill` exemplo: `taskkill /f /im notepad.exe` aí depois apaga o diretório...

Comment: @diegofm O workaround com robocopy funcionou!! Incrível. Se quiser responder..

Comment: @LaércioLopes Eu não sei quais são os executáveis (podem ser aplicativos externos), então teria que primeiro descobrir isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode testar essas duas opções abaixo. conforme [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98069/5524514) no SOEn:

> **Cuidado ao executar estes comandos!** Após executados, o processo é irreversível e pode causar danos a uma aplicação ou ao sistema operacional, caso seja executado em pastas do windows.

```
takeown /r /f [path da pasta]
cacls [path da pasta] /c /G "ADMINNAME":F /T
rmdir /s [path da pasta]
```

Outra alternativa para paths longos, que podem ocasionar erros com o método acima:

```
mkdir \empty
robocopy /mir \empty [path da pasta]
```

> Obs.: o usuário a executar ambos os comandos precisa ter privilégios elevados de administrador.